# Phrases for two methods that are different but both can solve the same task?

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to describe a type of pairs , that method1 and method2 have different implementations/settings, but both can be used to solve the same task.

My questions are:

1. Is there any terms/phrases or succinct ways to describe such pairs of methods?
2. How can I describe the relations of method1 and method2? Can I say "method1 is method2's *counterpart*/*peer*"?

Update:
method1 and method2 are not necessarily of the same quality. Each method may have its own pros and cons. For example, method1 might be easier to implement but slower; method2 might be hard to implement but faster.

Comment: Method1 and 2 are both 'solutions' to the problem. You could call them 'alternatives' - method1 is method2's alternate solution.

Comment: 1: ("either would) *suffice*". Both procedures will arrive with a (2:) '*congruent* solution'.

Comment: Are the two solutions of the same quality or not?

Comment: @Kat They may not. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The word ["alternative"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/alternative) would work here. It's pretty versatile, so it should cover your context. It can be used no matter the level of formality you want and can be used to describe a wide variety of things. Here are some examples:

- > We present two quicksort alternatives for cache optimizations which work well on both balanced and unbalanced data sets.
  >   <sub>[Improving Memory Performance of Sorting
  >   Algorithms](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.43.736&rep=rep1&type=pdf)</sub>
- > [Is ReactOS a viable Windows alternative? Taking the OS for a test drive](http://techgenix.com/reactos-windows-alternative/)
- > The preferred alternative to this method is `orElseThrow()`.
  >   <sub>[OptionalLong (Java SE 11 & JDK 11) - Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalLong.html)</sub>
- > Our selection actually contains more than 20 libraries, as some of them are alternatives to each other and solve the same problem.
  >   <sub>[Top 20 Python libraries for data science in 2018](https://activewizards.com/blog/top-20-python-libraries-for-data-science-in-2018/)</sub>

Comment: Nice. Answers both sub-questions with the same word. +1

Answer (score 10):

I would say that method1 is method2's **equivalent**:

> A person or thing that is equal to or corresponds with another in value, amount, function, meaning, etc.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/equivalent

Comment: I think this is better than @Laurel's *"alternative"* because with "equivalent" there is no insinuation of the methods being superior/inferior to one another.

Answer (score 8):

The term "functionally equivalent" springs to mind.

e.g. 
The methods are functionally equivalent.
or
A Functional equivalence exists between method1 and method2.

Comment: Given the update to the question this answer is no longer necessarily accurate; if the two solutions produce different results they may not, under some circumstances, be functionally equivalent but merely 'alternative solutions'. If the difference is merely in terms of difficulty to implement they will still be functionally equivalent, but if the run time differs and there is a time constraint on the output they may no longer be

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that what is salient isn't a property of a method (viz that it can solve a task that another method can solve), but rather a property of a task (that there are two methods that solve it). There's the phrase "there's more than one way to skin a cat".

Comment: Thanks! In this context, can I say "method1 is method2's counterpart/peer"? (see my updated question)

Comment: Method1 is Method2's *alternative*.

Answer (score 4):

[There's more than one way to skin a cat.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There%27s+more+than+one+way+to+skin+a+cat)

I think this is more appropriate as it more explicitly relates to processes for achieving something instead of a more abstract comparison.

Definition:

> There are many methods one may employ in achieving one's ends.

Used like so:

> We can go with method A if you like but there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Or "method B is just another way to skin *the* cat" ...

Comment: This is usually said after one method fails (and is much favoured by fictional villains). In any case, I'm not sure this phrase is actually applicable to expressing the relationship between two equally good choices and the example sentence you give seems to agree.

Comment: @tmgr I've updated the usage example. All the definitions of this phrase I can find make no mention of failure explicitly.

Comment: You're right - and I agree - I don't think failure is a necessary prelude to the phrase.

Answer (score 3):

*[All roads lead to Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_roads_lead_to_Rome)*:

> As a proverb, it refers to the fact that many routes can lead to a given result.

Answer (score 2):

Another metaphorical idiom would be ["That's six of one, half a dozen of the other"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/six%20of%20one) — i.e. it doesn't matter which, they are equivalent.

This idiom cannot be used to describe one method in relation to the other; I like the modification of the cat skinning metaphor suggested by JonM for that: "Method B is just another way to skin this cat", or similar.

Comment: This is far and away the most common phrase I'd hear in this context. You often hear _Six of one..._ with the rest of the phrase implied, much as with _Plus ça change..._

Comment: @tmgr You are welcome to upvote if you think it's a good answer ;-).

Comment: I definitely would... if it were a touch more expansive as an answer.

Comment: @tmgr I am unsure how I could improve it. I have submitted my 2 cents, provided a link and given my explanation. Any suggestions? Btw, feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: Well, OP has two questions. This is a great answer to the first question, not so much the second (but still very much a worthwhile answer). You could explain the phrase, talk about the context in which it is used and its usage (like the bit I mentioned about shortening), maybe even research its origin or first occurrence. I'd be curious! Plus you could include the relevant part of the definition you link to as an inline quote, to save readers clicking through. I won't be editing it, though I'll check back and upvote if you do!

Answer (score 1):

If both methods for solving the problem are equally good, regarding the choice between them you could say:

**It's as broad as it's long.**

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/it-s-as-broad-as-it-is-long) says this expression is

> used for saying that you cannot choose between two things or actions because they are equal

Macmillan also words the phrase slightly differently than I know it: *It's as broad as it is long*. It also lists the phrase as *British* and *spoken*.

The *spoken* is important. **This phrase is definitely conversational and not technical**: you wouldn't write it in a paper. Hence, this is really only an answer to your first question: *[Are] there any terms/phrases or succinct ways to describe such pairs of methods?*

I always took *it's as broad as it's long* to suggest a piece of wood that could be sat on either side: it wouldn't matter which, as it is square. That may well *not* be its actual origin, but it does express the equilateral geometry of the metaphor of the phrase.

With *it's as broad as it's long*, the essence is that it would make absolutely no difference if you went about solving the problem one way or the other, but the choice must between *two* equivalent options. (You could try *it's as broad as it's long as it's high* for three interchangeable alternatives, but at that point you've gone off piste and you're on your own.)

(Personally, I think the idea of exact equivalence might be more elegantly expressed by: *it's as broad as it's wide*. However, I couldn't recommend that as an option!)

Answer (score 0):

Such methods are **[two sides of the same coin](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/two+sides+of+the+same+coin)**:

> **Definition**
>   To be two things that seem disparate but are actually related.

Usage instance:

> "He gave me two methods for solving a problem, which are **two sides of the same coin**."

Comment: This would describe two methods which are actually the same even if they don't look like it at first sight. There is no suggestion of that in the OP: The two methods may be completely different ways to solve a given task. (E.g. you could repossess some stolen item or go to court. That's *not* two sides of the same coin but solves the given task.) Compare that to either offering a reward to your child for doing a chore or, alternatively, threatening with punishment; these could be considered two sides of the same coin (namely bribery).

Answer (score 0):

I would call the two methods *coequal*.

> **Definition**
>   Equal with another or each other in rank, **ability**, extent, etc.

Usage example:

> Methods 1 and 2 are coequal in their ability to handle the task.